# Dependency Injection with constructor parameters that aren't interfaces

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm still a newbie at DI, and I am trying to understand if I am thinking of things the wrong way.  I am working on a toy problem when I want to represent a Die object that has a dependency on an IRandomProvider.  That interface is simple:

```
public interface IRandomProvider 
{
   int GetRandom(int lower, int upper);
}
```

I want to have a Die constructor that looks like this:

```
Die(int numSides, IRandomProvider provider)
```

I'm trying to use a static DIFactory that has a method like this:

```
    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        if (kernel == null)
        {
            CreateKernel();
        }
        return kernel.Get<T>();
    }
```

Where CreateKernel simply binds to a specific implementation of IRandomProvider.

I want to be able to call this with:

```
DIFactory.Resolve<Die>(20);
```

I can't make this work without making a special version of "Resolve" which can allow me to deal with ConstructorArgs.  That seems to make things overly complex, and would require me to modify DIFactory for every other instance of that, as well as tie to a specific name for the constructor parameter.

If I refactor the Die class to not use the int constructor, everything works fine.  But now someone has to remeber to initialize the numSides parameter, which seems like a bad idea, since it is a requirement for the class.

I suspect this is a bad mental model for DI.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: btw: Aren't you meaning `Dice` and not `Die`? =)

Comment: No, Die is singular.  dice is plural.  I'll be implementing a Dice class that holds a number of dies, can check for doubles, etc.

Comment: I sometimes move the parameter from a constructor to a member function:
      int Roll(int numSides)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An inversion of control container is not a factory. Don't use it to resolve business objects like your `Die` class. Inversion Of Control is pattern used to let the container take control over the lifetime of your objects. A bonus of that is that it also supports the dependency injection pattern.

Business objects is typically created, changed and disposed. Hence no need to use the container for them. And as you just noticed, they do take their mandatory parameters in the constructor which makes it hard to use the container for them.

You can register a `DieFactory` in the container and let it take the `IRandomProvider` in the constructor:

```
public class DieFactory
{
    public DieFactory(IRandomProvider provider)
    {}

    public Die Create(int numberOfSides)
    {
        return new Die(numberOfSides, _provider);
    }
}
```

But it would of course be better to create a factory used to create all related business objects. Then you can take the kernel as a dependency:

```
public class AGoodNameFactory
{
    public DieFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {}

    public Die CreateDie(int numberOfSides)
    {
        var provider = _kernel.Resolve<IRandomProvider>();
        return new Die(numberOfSides, provider);
    }

    // other factories.
}
```

Or you could just take the `IRandomProvider` as a dependency directly in the class that creates the `Die` class.

Comment: This is very interesting.  Can you tell me the advantage of this approach over Akim's solution?  I come from old-school OO, and it looks like in your approach you only produce objects through factories?  Is there ever a time when you don't use a factory to create an object?

Comment: Not for simple entities no. imho the container should only be used to produce services and similar classes. i.e. classes that takes one or several entities (like `Die` and apply some logic on them).

Answer (score 5):

You could use `ConstructorArgument` together with `Kernel.Get` in this particular situation. 
Here is [full sample](http://pastebin.com/Fx0wUvLG).

### Module configuration

```
public class ExampleKernel : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IRandomProvider>()
            .To<RandomProvider>();

        Bind<Die>()
            .ToSelf()
            .WithConstructorArgument("numSides", 6);
                           //  default value for numSides
    }
}
```

### Resolving in code

```
var d6 = kernel.Get<Die>(); // default numSides value
var d20 = kernel.Get<Die>(new ConstructorArgument("numSides", 20)); // custom numSides

Assert.That(d6.NumSides == 6);
Assert.That(d20.NumSides == 20);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution.  The Bind.ToSelf never made sense to me, but now it it very clear.

Comment: It's a nice clear answer, but aren't we now back with the OP's problem "now someone has to remeber to initialize the numSides parameter, which seems like a bad idea, since it is a requirement for the class" ?